# Datalist showing data that is not in database

Tags: php, html

I have a `datalist` which is populated by data from database. In the meanwhile I droped my database and created another one, but with the same name, tables and everything, only some small changes.

Problem is that `datalists` are showing data from previous database. When I drop down `datalist`, first is shown data from current database, but then there is horizontal line, and below it old data is shown with yellow background. How can I stop `datalists` showing old data?

[image]

Comment: well, if the old db was dropped and the data do not exist anymore, it is 99% a cache problem. 
Did you test in a private navigation?

Comment: I did clear the cache from my browser, and it didn't help. Somehow it saves old data, that has earlier been in datalist..

Comment: @wdc Have you tried using another browser to see if it's browser-related?

Comment: Yeah, in ie it doesn't appear. I guess it has to do something with chrome..